# Recovering original image after blurring

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, scipy, convolution

I have the following code that applies Gaussian filter to an arbitrary image 25 times. Every time the filter is applied, the resulting image is normalized.

```
kernel = np.array([[1.0,2.0,1.0],
                  [2.0,4.0,2.0],
                  [1.0,2.0,1.0]])

for i in range(25):
    # handle each component separately
    img[:,:,0] = convolve(img[:,:,0], kernel, mode='same')
    img[:,:,1] = convolve(img[:,:,1], kernel, mode='same')
    img[:,:,2] = convolve(img[:,:,2], kernel, mode='same')
    img = img / 16 # normalize
```

What is the best way to reverse this process? I.e. if I have a blurred image (result of executing the code above) and want to get the original.

**Edit 1:**

Example

Original : [image: original]

Blurred:   [image: blurred]

**Edit 2:**

Attempt at reproducing Cris's answer

I installed `dipimage_2.9`. I am using `macOS 10.14.2` with `Matlab R2016a`.

It took me a while to get how to specify boundary conditions for convolutions, since DIPimage's `convolve.m` only accepts `image_in` and `kernel` args. I ended up using `dip_setboundary` for that ([DIPimage User Manual](ftp://qiftp.tudelft.nl/DIPimage/latest/docs/dipimage_user_manual.pdf) section 9.2).

Here's the code (I simply added `dip_setboundary` accordingly and the origin of crop region for `cut`):

```
% Get data
a = readim('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfSx2.png'); % using local path in real code
a = a{1}; % Keep only red channel

%% Create kernel
kernel = [1.0,2.0,1.0
          2.0,4.0,2.0
          1.0,2.0,1.0] / 16;
tmp = deltaim((size(kernel)-1)*25+1);
dip_setboundary('add_zeros');
for ii=1:25
    tmp = convolve(tmp,kernel);
end
kernel = tmp;

%% Apply convolution
dip_setboundary('periodic');
b = convolve(a,kernel);
dip_setboundary('symmetric'); % change back to default
% Find inverse operation
%   1- pad stuff so image and kernel have the same size
%      we maintain the periodic boundary condition for image b
b = repmat(b,ceil(imsize(kernel)./imsize(b)));
kernel = extend(kernel,imsize(b));
%   2- apply something similar to Wiener deconvolution
c = real(ift(ft(b)/(ft(kernel)+1e-6))); % Not exactly Wiener, but there's no noise!
%   3- undo padding
c = cut(c,imsize(a), [0, 0]); % upper left corner
```

Here's the resulting image `c`:

[image: after convolution]

Comment: Blurring is a loss-process -you can not reverse it 100% - essentially it is mergeing the values of surrounding cells weigted to the current one and averages it

Comment: @PatrickArtner I suspected that. Is it true even if I know the exact filter that was used to blur the image?

Comment: Look for deconvolution. Wiener deconvolution is the easiest solution for this problem. The inverse process is not (in general) perfect, as convolution *can* lose information. Understanding Fourier analysis is important to understand deconvolution.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I studied signal processing so I have a general understanding of this. I actually tried Wiener deconvolution but the results weren't good. My concern in this case is that for blurring convolution and normalization are applied many times one after another. Therefore simply applying deconvolution using the same kernel is not enough.

Comment: If I find time later today and this Q hasn’t been answered yet, I’ll write up an answer that show how to apply deconvolution in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the code in the question for a single channel, assuming `img` is a gray-scale image -- everything here can be applied per channel, so we don't need to repeat everything three times:

```
for i in range(25):
    img = ndimage.convolve(img, kernel)
    img = img / 16 # normalize
```

We'll get to undoing the convolution in a minute. First let's simplify the operation applied.

## Simplify the processing

The above is identical (within numerical precision) to:

```
kernel = kernel / 16 # Normalize
for i in range(25):
    img = ndimage.convolve(img, kernel)
```

This is true as long as `img` is not some integer type where clipping and/or rounding occurs. In general, with `*` the convolution, and `C` some constant,

```
g = C (f * h) = f * (C h)
```

Next, we know that applying the convolution 25 times is the same as applying the convolution once with a composite kernel,

```
g = (((f * h) * h) * h) * h = f * (h * h * h * h)
```

How can we obtain the composite kernel? Applying a convolution to an image that is all zeros and with a 1 in the middle pixel yields the kernel again, so that

```
delta = np.zeros(kernel.shape)
delta[delta.shape[0]//2, delta.shape[1]//2] = 1
kernel2 = ndimage.convolve(delta, kernel)
kernel2 == kernel # is true everywhere, up to numerical precision
```

Thus, the following code finds the kernel that is used to smooth the image in the question:

```
kernel = np.array([[1.0,2.0,1.0],
                  [2.0,4.0,2.0],
                  [1.0,2.0,1.0]]) / 16
delta = np.zeros(((kernel.shape[0]-1)*25+1, (kernel.shape[1]-1)*25+1))
delta[delta.shape[0]//2, delta.shape[1]//2] = 1
for i in range(25):
    delta = ndimage.convolve(delta, kernel)
kernel = delta
```

This kernel will be very similar to a Gaussian kernel due to the central limit theorem.

Now we can obtain the same output as in the question with a single convolution:

```
output = ndimage.convolve(img, kernel)
```

## Inverting the convolution

The process of inverse filtering is called deconvolution. In theory this is a very trivial process, but in practice it is very difficult due to noise, an inexact knowledge of the kernel, etc.

We know that we can compute the convolution through the Fourier domain:

```
output = np.convolve(img, kernel, mode='wrap')
```

is the same as

```
output = np.real(np.fft.ifft2( np.fft.fft2(img) * np.fft.fft2(np.fft.ifftshift(kernel)) ))
```

(assuming that `kernel` is the same size as `img`, we'd typically have to pad it with zeros first). Any differences between spatial and frequency domain operation results are caused by the how the image is extended past its boundary when using `convolve`. The Fourier method assumes a periodic boundary condition, this is why I used the `'wrap'` mode for the convolution here.

The inverse operation is simply a division in the Fourier domain:

```
img = np.real(np.fft.ifft2( np.fft.fft2(output) / np.fft.fft2(np.fft.ifftshift(kernel)) ))
```

For this to work, we need to know the exact values of `kernel`, and there should be no noise added in the process. For `output` computed as above, this should give the exact result in theory

However, some kernels could be exactly zero for some frequency components (i.e. `np.fft.fft2(np.fft.ifftshift(kernel))` contains zeros). These frequencies cannot be recovered, and dividing by 0 will lead to NaN values that will spread through the whole image in the inverse transform, the inverse image will be all NaNs.

For a Gaussian kernel there are no zeros, so this should not happen. However there will be many frequencies that are very nearly zero. The Fourier transform of `output` will therefore also have very small value for these elements. The inverse process then is the division of a very small value by another very small value, causing numerical precision issues.

And you can see how this process, if there is only a very little bit of noise, will greatly enhance this noise, such that the output is given almost entirely by this noise.

The Wiener deconvolution includes regularization to prevent these issues with noise and numerical imprecision. Basically, you prevent the division by very small numbers by adding a positive value to the Fourier transform of `kernel`. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_deconvolution) has a good description of Wiener deconvolution.

## Demo

I'm using MATLAB with DIPimage 3 here to do a quick demo (much less effort for me than firing up Python and figuring out how to do all of this there). This is the code:

```matlab
% Get data
a = readim('https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfSx2.png');
a = a{1}; % Keep only red channel

% Create kernel
kernel = [1.0,2.0,1.0
          2.0,4.0,2.0
          1.0,2.0,1.0] / 16;
tmp = deltaim((size(kernel)-1)*25+1);
for ii=1:25
    tmp = convolve(tmp,kernel,'add zeros');
end
kernel = tmp;

% Apply convolution
b = convolve(a,kernel,'periodic');

% Find inverse operation
%   1- pad stuff so image and kernel have the same size
%      we maintain the periodic boundary condition for image b
b = repmat(b,ceil(imsize(kernel)./imsize(b)));
kernel = extend(kernel,imsize(b));
%   2- apply something similar to Wiener deconvolution
c = ift(ft(b)/(ft(kernel)+1e-6),'real'); % Not exactly Wiener, but there's no noise!
%   3- undo padding
c = cut(c,imsize(a),'top left');
```

This is the output, the top third is the input image, the middle third is the blurred image, the bottom third is the output image:

[image: output of code above]

Important to note here is that I used a periodic boundary condition for the initial convolution, which matches what happens in the Fourier transform. Other boundary conditions will cause artefacts in the inverse transform near the edges. Because the kernel size is larger than the image, the whole image will be one big artefact, and you won't be able to recover anything. Also note that, to pad the kernel with zeros to the size of the image, I had to replicate the image, since the kernel is larger than the image. Replicating the image matches again the periodic boundary condition imposted by the Fourier transform. Both of these tricks could be ignored if the input image were much larger than the convolution kernel, as you would expect in a normal situation.

Also note that, without the regularization in the deconvolution, the output is all NaN, because we are dividing very small values by very small values. The Fourier transform of the kernel has a lot of near-zeros in it because the blurring is quite heavy.

Finally, note that adding even a small amount of noise to the blurred image will make it impossible to deconvolve the image in a way that the text can be read. The inverse transform will look very nice, but the text strokes will be distorted enough for the letters to no longer be easily recognizable:

[image: same as above, but with a little bit of noise added after blurring]

---

The code above uses DIPimage 3, which doesn't yet have an official binary to install, it needs to be build from [source](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib). To run the code using DIPimage 2.x a few changes are necessary:

1. The boundary condition must be set using `dip_setboundary`, instead of being able to pass it directly to the `convolve` function. The strings `'add zeros'` and `'periodic'` are the boundary condition.
2. The `ft` and `ift` functions use a symmetric normalization, each multiplies their output by `1/sqrt(prod(imsize(image)))`, whereas in DIPimage 3 the normalization is the more common multiplication by `1/prod(imsize(image))` for `ift`, and `1` for `ft`. This means that the Fourier transform of `kernel` must be multiplied by `sqrt(prod(imsize(kernel)))` to match the result of DIPimage 3:

   ```
   c = real(ift(ft(b)/((ft(kernel)*sqrt(prod(imsize(kernel))))+1e-6)));
   ```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! A single convolution with the kernel that you suggested gives me an output that looks very similar to the output of the original process. I tried both deconvolution techniques that you mentioned (frequency domain division and Wiener deconvolution using scikit-image) and the result was too noisy. Can you please take a look and double check if it's at all possible to restore the originals for my case? I added sample images (before and after blurring) to the question. My main goal is to be able to at least discern some characters after deconvolution.

Comment: @MaxLawnboy: Yes, it is possible to undo the blurring. See the edit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @CrisLuengo for following up. I installed `DIPimage` and tried reproducing the answer but the result doesn't look right at all. I followed your code almost word for word but had to change a few things related to boundary conditions that you didn't specify explicitly. Can you please take a look at the edited question; it's my first time using `DIPimage`.

Comment: @MaxLawnboy: See the edit. I'm using DIPimage 3, which has some significant changes. The different normalization in `ft` means that: (1) the regularization parameter is too large by a factor 84.85, making  the output too smooth, and (2) the image `c` is scaled by a factor 84.85, the output image you show is the result of casting those values to `uint8`, wrapping values that are too large in a manner consistent with (modulo 255) arithmetic. By properly scaling the result of `ft(kernel)` I get the same results I get with DIPimage 3.

Answer (score 0):

You cant - blurring looses information by averaging.

Consider a 1-dim example:

```
[1  2  1]   on    [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]  assuming 0 for missing "pixel" on convolution
```

results in  `[4, 8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 20]`. The **8** could come from `[1,2,3]` but also from `[2,1,4]` - so you already have 2 different solutions. Wich ever you take , influences whatever values might have been the source for **12**.

This is an overly simplyfied example - you can solve this - but in image processing you might deal with 3000*2000 pixels and 2d-convolutions by 3x3,5x5,7x7,... matrices making the reversing impractical.

Make this two dimensional you *might* be able to solve it mathematically - but more often then not you get a miriad of solutions and very complex constrains to solve it if you apply this to a 2-dimensional convolution and 3000*2000 pixels.

Comment: Your example is incorrect, the first element of the result should be 4, and the last 20. And for this example, the inverse operation leads to 7 equations with 7 unknowns, if there are no redundant equations, as I suspect is the case here, this can be solved.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  - I choose to apply the convolution only in pixels that have neighbors fitting the convolution- so neither [1, ...] nor [..., 7] was convoluted. Whatever is done to border pixels is specified by the mode of the method used,see f.e. https://scipy.github.io/devdocs/tutorial/ndimage.html#filter-functions and scroll down to the `mode` explanations. Your interpretation would be a mode of constant with 0 as constant. Consider applying this 2-dim to a 3000*2000 image and try to solve it mathematically - you might find one unique solution, you might find multiple - hence the operation

Comment: @CrisLuengo  - is not bijective. Even if you solved it, it would take some time. The example I gave is overly simplified and does also not adress multiple applications of the convolition.

Comment: That link does not show a mode that does as you do here. In 20 years of image processing, I hadn’t seen a filter applied in this manner, with the edge pixels copied unmodified. Regarding the inverse operation: yes, often it is an ill-posed problem. My comment here was to indicate that your example is not a good one because it is easy to compute that inverse.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I just had a few lectures in CV and worked for a year on itso youre experience is probably more reasonable. I did also not find any such "mode" in scipy. Fixed the example.